# How to uninstall OpenCV in mac

Tags: macos, opencv

I installed OpenCV this way

```
#After downloading OpenCV-3.0, in the directory:
echo "#define GTEST_USE_OWN_TR1_TUPLE 1" | cat > temp1
cat modules/ts/include/opencv2/ts/ts_gtest.h > temp2
cat temp1 temp2 > modules/ts/include/opencv2/ts/ts_gtest.h
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -Wno-dev
make -j8 && sudo make install
#Update your bash_profile:
~$ echo "export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH" >>
~/.bash_profile
#Close and open the Terminal
#Open python console and try to import cv2 to test if everything works
~$ python import cv2
```

The version is not stable and making errors I want to uninstall it to avoid problem when I install opencv using brew, should I just delete the folder ?

THis what I get when i did

```
cd build
 make uninstall
-- Uninstalling "/usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/libippicv.a"
CMake Error at cmake_uninstall.cmake:20 (MESSAGE):
  Problem when removing "/usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/libippicv.a"


make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/uninstall] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/uninstall.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/uninstall.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [uninstall] Error 2
```

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to remove this? I'm running into the same issue even with `sudo`

Answer (score 8):

If you used Homebrew to install you can use this command.

`brew uninstall opencv3`

You will not have to remove any directory such as `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3`

Comment: Surely he didn't use homebrew.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to the build directory and run `sudo make uninstall`
2. Delete that line you added to ~/.bashrc
3. Remove the opencv directory

Comment: Emphasis on the `sudo` in make uninstall. That's probably why it failed for you

Comment: I tried this but even with `sudo` I ran into the same issue